# CakePHP Form with TwitterBoostrap (controls controls-row)

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put two inputs side by side in cakePHP using TwitterBoostrap.

This is my piece of code

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Ad',array("class"=>"well row-fluid")); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Ad'); ?></legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('user_id',array('class'=>'span3'));?>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('state_id', array('empty' => 'Selecione o Estado','class'=>'span2','div'=));?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('city_id', array('empty' => 'Selecione a Cidade','class'=>'span5'));?>
        </div>
```

The output looks like it:

```
State
|----------| City
             |----------|
```

City isnt aligned. How can I solve it?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Bootstrap with CakePHP, I've often found it useful by working back from the HTML I wish to create. If I understand your question correctly, you would like to produce the following:

```
<form class="well-row">
    <div class="span3">
        <label class="control-label">State</label>
        <select name="state">...</select>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <label class="control-label">City</label>
        <select name="state">...</select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am aware that CakePHP's form helper does surround `input` and `label` elements with `div` tags which will mess with your layout. I usually do the following to give me greater control over the markup:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Ad', array('inputDefaults' => array('div' => false)))?>
```

To summarize, try the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Ad', array('inputDefaults' => array('div' => false)))?>
<div class="span5">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('state_id', array('empty' => 'Selecione o Estado', 'class' => 'span3'));?>
</div>
<div class="span5">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('city_id', array('empty' => 'Selecione a Cidade', 'class' => 'span3'));?>
</div>
```

You may have to increase the span of the container divs to accommodate for any padding on the label or select elements to stop them from wrapping.